# Force recomposition of Composable in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

After one user blocks another I call popBackStack() so it leaves the blocked user's profile. But I also want to reload the page where the user lands after he called popBackStack() so that the LaunchedEffect(Unit) gets called again and the updated list (which no longer contains the content of the blocked user) is fetched from the backend.

How can I do that?

I use saveState and restoreState in my navigation but in this case, I don't want them.
The posts of the blocked user should no longer be visible after blocking him. But unfortunately after restoring the state the posts of the blocked users are still saved in the lists all around the app.

Comment: Hi you will find your answer in this link, video is all about lifecycle events control in jetpack compose UI                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                           
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z0u29gRGe4U

Comment: @SyedIbrahim yes I know about lifecycle events in jetpack compose but how is this gonna help me? You mean I should put something in my onResume function of that composable? But what should I put in there? I only want to reload the composable after the user returns from blocking another user.

Comment: Please provide details on your question and what have you tried so far.. it’s impossible to answer based on assumptions. That’s called a suggestion and not the actual answer.

Comment: @JeelVankhede So my goal is (after a user blocks another user) to reload every screen the user enters. The problem is that I use restoreState = true so the screens in my app got previously preloaded. So even after blocking a user you can see the content of this user all around the app. I wish there would be a way to clear all saveState's in the navController, but there is none.

Comment: Right now only when you restart the application the lists are up-to-date. But I want to reload every possible list and screen in my app right after the user blocks another user.
A function like navController.removeAllSavedStates() would be a dream which forces every navigation destination to build up freshly and not restore its state with outdated data.

Comment: One way of handling this issue is by updating your data model from view model, so that your state changes upon subscription inside your composable function.

Comment: Every time you enter any screen/fragment, you refresh data model which eventually recomposes your composable.

Comment: I only want to update the screen on entering when the user blocked another user.
In all other cases I want that savedState behaviour.

I think we are talking about different things, maybe I wasn't explaining my problem good enough.

Isn't there a simple way to just reload a composable as if I would call navController.navigate() the first time.
So that it calls the LaunchedEffect(Unit) block again

Comment: Perhaps you should consider supplying a sensible `key` to that `LaunchedEffect`  instead of a `Unit` that you are sure will change every time you navigate back to its containing composable scope(screen). Or maybe a shared `ViewModel` where your hosted screens observes a state that you can check conditionally.